# OpenSSL - Find the AES key

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, aes, ssl

I created a SSL socket in C between a client and a host using the OpenSSL library.
I need the AES key of a SSL session to encrypt correctly a message and I can't use the standard functions ssl_write and ssl_read.
I found that there is a struct called AES_KEY, but I don't know how I can found it!

SSL_write and SSL_read work correctly only with packet type: 23 ("Application protocol")

How can I decrypt, for example, an SSL Hello Message that come from server (i opened the SSL channel with this server)? How can I encrypt an SSL Hello Client (it's in clair) that comes from an other client?

I'm trying to demonstrate an attack during the phase of "TLS Renegotiation" of TLS Protocol. I'm trying to simulate an attack MITM with a custom proxy.

Now, the server send to proxy a certain number of encrypted messages of type 22 (Handshake) and 20 (ChangeCipherSpec). How can I read these messages and decrypt them? The standard library ssl_read works only with messages 23 (Application).

Moreover, the client send to proxy a client Hello and other messages of type 22 and 20. How can I write these messages and encrypt them? I tried using ssl_write, but the server doesn't understand these messages.

Comment: "I can't use the standard functions ssl_write and ssl_read"  Why?

Comment: Because I want to send personalized handshake messages.

Comment: It's nice that you want to send personalized handshake messages.  But it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: During the renegotiation phase, handshake messages are crypted with AES and then hashed with MD5. I want to decrypt these messages, without continuing the transparent renegotiation phase.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution. The functions are:

```
int ssl3_read_bytes (SSL *s, int type, unsigned char *buf, int len, int peek);
int ssl3_write_bytes (SSL *s, int type, const void *buf_, int len);
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of manually (en|de)crypting records, you should use [SSL_CTX_set_info_callback](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_info_callback.html) to get at the information you want.

Comment: Thank you... So I have to call a callback for the SSL_connect, generate the AES key manually and then call an other callback for SSL_write() and SSL_read()? By this way I can personalize messages but I have to manage a lot of problems for the keys generation. I can't understand where is stocked the SSL private key, used for the encryption/decryption operations.

Comment: You're not supposed to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, for a normal use you are right, but I'm trying to demonstrate an attack the type TLS renegotiation to pass an exam.

Comment: Fine, but now we've reached the point where I point out that the software is open source.

Comment: I know that is open source: I read a part of the code, but I can't find the AES key of the session.

Comment: Perhaps, also, it might take more work than you think.  And perhaps, since I don't get credit for the exam, I'm not inclined to do that work.

Comment: I found an other TLS library (http://polarssl.org/) that permit, for example, making custom ssl_clienthello... I don't understand why OpenSSL doesn't allow the creation of these type of message with a simple library function.

Comment: OpenSSL doesn't allow it because if you want an SSL-wrapped connection, it's not something you would ever need to do. If you want to do something outside the normal usage of the protocol, write your own library (or modify an open-source one)